# django admin asynchron reloading form for foreignkey fild

Tags: django, python-3.x

How refresh django admin form when a value change in the browser? I searched and found a similar question:
[How refresh django admin form when a value change in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929976/how-refresh-django-admin-form-when-a-value-change-in-the-browser). But the problem is that I can not use one library because I need to change the model. Another library djano-flexselect is not supported for python3((

```
class Country(m.Model):
......................


class Region(m.Model):
    company = m.ForeignKey(Country)
    name = m.CharField(max_length=80)


class City(m.Model):
    region = m.ForeignKey(Region)
    country = m.ForeignKey(Country)
```

When adding a new city, I need to select a country and then the form with the region will automatically reload all the regions associated with the selected country.
Can anyone help?